# cant shuffle both arrays without getting crossover and values that are out of range

Tags: arrays, delphi, shuffle

I have two arrays that I want to shuffle.  below you will see the declarations and an example of the shuffle.

```
var
  highNums : array[1..9] of integer;
  lowNums  : array[1..20] of integer;
begin
  Q := 0;

  for I := 1 to Length(highNums) do
  begin
    highNums[I] := q;
  end;

  for K := 1 to Length(lowNums) do
  begin
    lowNums[K] := q;
  end;


bigNums[] {25 ..225} every 25
lowNumes[] {1..10} two of each number

procedure shuffleHighArray();
var
  I, ToSwapHigh, HighTemp : integer;
begin
  for I := 1 to length(highNums) do
  begin
    toSwapHigh := Random(length(highNums));
    HighTemp := highNums[I];
    highNums[I] := highNums[toSwapHigh];
    highNums[toSwapHigh] := HighTemp;
  end;
end;


procedure shuffleLowArray();
var
  K, ToSwapLow, LowTemp : integer;
begin
  for K := 1 to length(lowNums)  do
  begin
    toSwapLow := random(length(lowNums));
    LowTemp := lowNums[K];
    lowNums[K] := lowNums[toSwapLow];
    lowNums[toSwapLow] := LowTemp;
  end;
 end;
```

here are procedures I am using along with the declarations of both arrays.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Be aware that Random(N) returns a number in the range 0..N-1, while your arrays have a low index of 1.

Comment: @Lee: it is not really clear to me what your question is. Please clarify, otherwise your question risks being downvoted or even closed. Up to now, it looks as if you want us to debug your code. That is not what S.O. is for. And the Delphi debugger is very good and convenient, so I suggest you start debugging yourself. Uwe's comment suggests you may have some one-off errors. These are easy to find by debugging. You may also want to read up about parameters, so you only need one shuffle function for any array of integers.

Comment: Oh, and please post a [MCVE]. The code above doesn't compile, as is, so we can't try it and see what is wrong with it. Always make it as easy as possible for the people who might answer, so they don't have to jump through hoops to help **you** out. They spend their valuable time helping, and if you post uncompilable code, you just waste their time. This means many of them won't be inclined to help **you** and move on to other, better answerable questions.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.    I think I am making this more difficult then I need to, but here is what I am trying to do.  have two arrays, HighNums[] with values 25-225 in increments of 25.  the LowNums[] 1-10 having two of each value.  I want to shuffle them each separately.  I am pretty sure that the issue is in the shuffle of each array.  I will just try to figure out another way.  (this was the first time asking here, thanks for the pointers on post edicute!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a generic method for shuffle your array.

I've written this for you:

```
uses
  System.Math;

type
  TArrayHelper = class abstract
  public
    class constructor Create;
    class procedure PermuteArray<T>(var A: array of T);
  end;


{ TArrayHelper }

class constructor TArrayHelper.Create;
begin
  Randomize;
end;

class procedure TArrayHelper.PermuteArray<T>(var A: array of T);
var
  Tmp: T;
  i, j: Integer;
begin
  for i := High(A) downto low(A) do
  begin
    j := RandomRange(0, i);
    Tmp := A[i];
    A[i] := A[j];
    A[j] := Tmp;
  end;
end;
```

If you want to test it. Place a button and a Memo on a form and then try this code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  procedure DisplayArray(A: array of Integer);
  var
    i: Integer;
    s: String;
  begin
    s := '[';
    for i := low(A) to min(10, High(A)) do
      s := s + A[i].ToString + ',';

    s[Length(s)] := ']';
    Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
  end;

var
  i: Integer;
  Nums: array [1 .. 9000] of Integer;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;

  for i := low(Nums) to High(Nums) do
    Nums[i] := i;

  DisplayArray(Nums);
  TArrayHelper.PermuteArray(Nums);
  DisplayArray(Nums);
end;
```

Comment: WOW, Thank you so much.  I have not really been able to fully understand or implement objects I will work on understanding this code.  this gives me a great place to start!

Comment: Feel free to ask